# Drawing a line using 2 points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcobjects

I was trying to create a Basetool which will collect points onMouseDown event. I was trying my tool to draw a line with the points collected. To collect points I used List. I am just putting the code here.

```
            IPoint screenPoint;
            screenPoint = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point();
            screenPoint.X = X;
            screenPoint.Y = Y;

            IScreenDisplay screenDisplay = (m_application.Document as IMxDocument).ActiveView.ScreenDisplay;
            IPoint mapPoint  = screenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(X, Y);
            point.Add(mapPoint); // Point is List of IPoints
```

Using 2 MOuseDown, I want to collect 2 points and pass the putCoords method the points to create a Line. Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: You need to show the full code. We don't know if you are capturing into a graphic or edit sketch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a [polyline geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000045t000000) you can create one using an [IPointCollection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m00000275000000) as a [Path](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000045n000000):

```
object gMissing = System.Type.Missing;

IPointCollection pOutPntColl = new PathClass(); // a new path
pOutPntColl.AddPoint(point[0], ref gMissing, ref gMissing); // add first point
pOutPntColl.AddPoint(point[1], ref gMissing, ref gMissing); // add 2nd point

IGeometryCollection pOutGeomColl = new PolylineClass(); // a new polyline
pOutGeomColl.AddGeometry((IGeometry)pOutPntColl, ref gMissing, ref gMissing); // add this path

IGeometry pOutGeom = (IGeometry)pOutGeomColl; // cast the geometry collection to a geometry
pOutGeom.SpatialReference = (m_application.Document as IMxDocument).FocusMap.SpatialReference; // set the spatial reference
```

A PolyLine is made from one (or more) paths so is constructed from an [IGeometryCollection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000001v1000000) (supporting multi-part geometries) which is then cast to an [IGeometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGeometry_Interface/002m000001rm000000/) or [IPolyline](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000002p0000000) allowing you to set the SpatialReference.

A related (and helpful) object in this case would be an [IRubberBand](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000002q5000000)
as new [RubberLine](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000003s7000000), on TrackNew this will attach a stretchy line to your cursor from your first clicked point and then allow you to grab the last point when the tracking is finished.